# c++ heap corruption dectected

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, heap-corruption

I am getting an heap corruption error when running a code from my textbook.However, when I run it through an online compiler, it works. I am using visual studio 2013. I assume the code is correct; Is it might be something wrong with my visual studio? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    srand(time(0));
    int* counts[10];
    // Allocate the rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        counts[i] = new int[i + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            counts[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    const int RUNS = 1000;
    // Simulate 1,000 balls
    for (int run = 0; run < RUNS; run++)
    {
        // Add a ball to the top
        counts[0][0]++;
        // Have the ball run to the bottom
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int r = rand() % 2;
            // If r is even, move down,
            // otherwise to the right
            if (r == 1)
            {
                j++;
            }
            counts[i][j]++;
        }
    }
    // Print all counts
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << counts[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // Deallocate the rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        delete[] counts[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        counts[i] = new int[i + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            counts[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

for `counts[0]` you allocate memory for only one int (`counts[0] = new int[0+1]`). In inner loop you try to access `counts[0][1]`. Therefore, you go beyond the boundaries of the array and get heap corruption.

Comment: oh..I see what you are saying. but how do I allocate the 2nd int? in the inner loop? sorry I'm very new to c++

Comment: @Ace_J  I do not quite understand what you want to do, but you could try something like `counts[i] = new int[i + 2];`

Comment: I tried int[i+2], still gives me the same thing. I also tried        `srand(time(0));
 int**counts = new int*[10];
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
  counts[i] = new int[i + 1];

 }` doesn't work neither :(

Comment: @Ace_J I just check with `counts[i] = new int[i+2];` - it's work fine in my VS2010. Check all once more time.

Comment: no error message this time, but still the incorrect output: The first two lines are correct starting the 3rd line it became something like 243 508-842150202. I even reinstalled my VS.

Comment: @Ace_J Try to change `for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++)` to `for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)`

Comment: OMG it worked! Thank you so so much! Although can you explain the reasoning behind this? Why did it work on yours but not on mine?

Comment: @Ace_J You just need to more carefully check your code